# Will Duplex Channel's State in NetTcpBinding automatically transition accordingly to client's?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5

On client side, I handle the proxy state so that when its State==CommunicationState.Faulted, it will automatically call Abort() and gracefully transition to CommunicationState.Closed.
On server side, I have 2 events hooked up to callback channel

`OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += Channel_Faulted;`
`OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += Channel_Closed;`

Here are my events code

```
private void Channel_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var callback = sender as IPtiCommunicationCallback;
    PtiClient client;
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        client = clientsList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == callback).Key;
    }
    if (client != null)
    {
        //Code to remove client from the list
        Disconnect(client);
    }
}

private void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ICommunicationObject).Abort();
}
```

Now the question: Will the duplex channel's (the callback channel) state automatically transition accordingly to client's or I have to handle the Faulted State as I did? I'm using NetTcpBinding by the way.

Comment: I have developed wcf duplex service and those  event not properly fired over the internet. 
SO that I check the connection state every 10 minutes using timer.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about why they are not properly fired? And what binding did you use? Right now I only concern about nettcpbinding over intranet. But it's good to know more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Callback channel's state will generally mimic the client's state, but this is **not guaranteed**. For example, if the client is trying to reach the server to close the connection, its state might be `Closing` while the state on the server side could be `Opened`. You are handling it correctly in assuming that each side must handle `Closed` and `Faulted` states individually.

Answer (score 0):

I have done bit research about what kind of binding should we use and finally decided to go ahead with nettcp binding. See my blog for detail explanation.

http://maheshde.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/duplex-communication-over-internet.html

I have no idea why those events not fired. But triggering WCF call from client every 10 minutes our problem solved.